# What is the better command line xsd generator tool in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

What is the best command line xsd generator  tool in java. I want to read some xhtml page online and  generate xsd programmatically so that I can use jaxb to unmarshal the xhtml document .

Comparions of the available tools including xmlBeans, xml2xsd,oxygenxml, stylus studio , Trang etc.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If you remove the word "best" and the request for comparisons, this question wouldn't be closed very soon... Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn about what type of question fits the Stack Overflow Q&A format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why generate it? XHTML is well-defined. Use this XSD here:

http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd

From this XSD, you can generate JAXB-annotated POJO's using XJC. Some documentation can be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html

I don't think there's any need for a discussion about a "best" tool, as XJC is a Java reference implementation for such a tool

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your reply. Actually i want to unmarshal the xhtml form this link view-source:http://www.google.com/m/products/detail?cid=14154127892370052561&hl=en&loc=us#prd:o

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your reply. Actually i want to unmarshal the xhtml form this link view-source:http://www.google.com/m/products/detail?cid=14154127892370052561&hl=en&loc=us#prd:o  , xjc http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd  gives error : [ERROR] java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
  line 33 of http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd

Comment: You can download the XSD and run XJC on a local copy

Comment: I've downloaded the xsd and usded the command , but it gives error:[ERROR] Property "Lang" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 302 of file:/opt/downloads/test/xhtml1-strict.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 303 of file:/opt/downloads/test/xhtml1-strict.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.

Comment: My problem was not solved , could u please help?

Comment: I'm sorry. This is a bit out of scope for a regular Q&A... I can't solve this problem for you...